# Get data from two tables in specified format

Tags: mysql, database

I am not very pro in database thus seeking for an effective way to solve below problem. As have solved it but using to many union and sub query but those do not seem ideal.

```
INSERT INTO teacher(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO teacher(id, name) VALUES(2, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO teacher(id, name) VALUES(3, 'Chris');
INSERT INTO teacher(id, name) VALUES(4, 'John');
*************************************************************
INSERT INTO subject(id, name, teacherId) VALUES(1, 'DSA', 1);
INSERT INTO subject(id, name, teacherId) VALUES(2, 'OPPS', 2);
INSERT INTO subject(id, name, teacherId) VALUES(3, 'JAVA', 2);
```

My expected output is;
Mike  1
Jim 2
Chris 0
John 0

Explanation:
1. Name of each teacher along with the associated subject. 
2. Number of the subject associated with each teacher i.e. 0,1,2 etc
3. Name of the teachers who are not assigned to any subject.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: count with left join and group by

Answer (score 0):

The below query will help you

```
select t.name, count(s.name) from teacher t
left join subject s on s.teacherId = t.id
group by t.name;
```

You need to join both the tables on teacher's id
and then count the names of subjects.

[LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) is used so that you get data from `teacher` table even if you don't have data in `subject` table

[GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) is used to aggregate `subject name` over each individual teacher

Answer (score 0):

This is an efficient way to do this without using any join. I used to query in this way to avoid LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT
  `name`,
  (SELECT COUNT(id)
   FROM `subject`
   WHERE subject.teacherId = teacher.id)    'count'
FROM teacher;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all

```
select t.name ,count(s.*) as nbr from teacher t,subject s where t.id=s.teacherId 
group by t.name
union all 
select t.name ,0 as nbr from teacher t where id not in ( select teacherId from subject)
```